In Swift I am getting WebSocket receive error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=57 "Socket is not connected" all the time
In my swift code I have opened a websocket connection with eleven labs and am sending it text and getting back chunks of audio data in stream that I want to play continuously and start the playback as soon as the first chunk arrives.
But it only plays a very small part of the text and then stops abruptly and I see the error :
WebSocket receive error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=57 "Socket is not connected"
Audio player error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1954115647 "(null)"
My code is :
class WebSocketViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, URLSessionWebSocketDelegate {
    private var webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask?
    private var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    private var audioBuffer = Data()

    func connectAndPlay() {
        let urlString = "wss://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/voice-id/stream-input?model_id=eleven_turbo_v2"
           guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
               print("Invalid URL")
               return
           }
           
           var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
        webSocketTask = session.webSocketTask(with: request)
        webSocketTask?.resume()
        sendInitialMessages(apiKey: apiKey)
    }

    private func sendInitialMessages(apiKey: String) {
        let bosMessage: [String: Any] = [
            "text": " ",
            "voice_settings": [
                "stability": 0.5,
                "similarity_boost": 0.8
            ],
            "xi_api_key": apiKey
        ]

        sendMessage(bosMessage)

        let textMessage: [String: Any] = [
            "text": "Hello World this is just a random message for testing purposes",
        ]

        sendMessage(textMessage)

        let eosMessage: [String: Any] = [
            "text": ""
        ]

        sendMessage(eosMessage)
    }

    private func sendMessage(_ message: [String: Any]) {
        do {
            let messageData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: message, options: [])
            let messageString = String(data: messageData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
            let webSocketMessage = URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.string(messageString)
            webSocketTask?.send(webSocketMessage) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("WebSocket send error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("JSON serialization error: \(error)")
        }
    }


    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didOpenWithProtocol protocol: String?) {
        print("WebSocket connection opened")
        receiveMessages()
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didCloseWith closeCode: URLSessionWebSocketTask.CloseCode, reason: Data?) {
        print("WebSocket connection closed")
    }

    private func receiveMessages() {
        webSocketTask?.receive { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("WebSocket receive error: \(error)")
            case .success(let message):
                switch message {
                case .string(let text):
                    self?.handleMessage(text)
                default:
                    break
                }
                self?.receiveMessages()
            }
        }
    }

    private func handleMessage(_ text: String) {
        guard let data = text.data(using: .utf8),
              let response = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else { return }

        if let audioBase64 = response["audio"] as? String {
                    addToAudioBuffer(audioBase64)
                    if player == nil || !player!.isPlaying {
                        playAudio()
                    }
                }

        if let isFinal = response["isFinal"] as? Bool, isFinal {
            print("Audio generation is complete.")
        }

    }
    
    private func addToAudioBuffer(_ base64String: String) {
           guard let audioData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) else {
               print("Failed to decode base64 audio data")
               return
           }
           audioBuffer.append(audioData)
       }

    private func playAudio() {
        guard !audioBuffer.isEmpty else {
                    print("Audio buffer is empty")
                    return
                }

                do {
                    player = try AVAudioPlayer(data: audioBuffer)
                    player?.play()
                } catch {
                    print("Audio player error: \(error)")
                }

                audioBuffer.removeAll()
    }
}


Observations, why do you have class WebSocketViewModel
declared as ObservableObject,
since you are not using @Publishing for any variables, not even audioBuffer.
On what line of your code do you get the error?

Ah yes it. no longer needs to be ObservableObject, thanks.
Its printing this line print("WebSocket receive error: (error)") My audio plays but just one or two chunks and then abruptly stops.

I am also seeing this in console :
nw_flow_add_write_request [C1 -916217822:443 failed parent-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en1[802.11], uses wifi)] cannot accept write requests
Even though I have allowed wifi in info.plist
